# How could I use `each_index` to print the index of each element?

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, indexing

I have an array

```
array = [ "mm,GATO,nn",  "mm,GATO,nn",
          "mm,PERRO,nn", "mm,PERRO,nn",
          "mm,LOBO,nn",  "mm,LOBO,nn"  ]
```

I need to use `each_index` to obtain

```
array = [ "mm,GATO,nn1",  "mm,GATO,nn2",
          "mm,PERRO,nn1", "mm,PERRO,nn2",
          "mm,LOBO,nn1",  "mm,LOBO,nn2"  ]
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: what are you trying to do, what should the result look like, what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you just numbering duplicate strings? In that case, you could use a counter hash:

```
array = ["mm,GATO,nn","mm,GATO,nn","mm,PERRO,nn","mm,PERRO,nn","mm,LOBO,nn","mm,LOBO,nn"]
counter = Hash.new(0)
array.map! do |word|
  word + (counter[word] += 1).to_s
end

p array
# ["mm,GATO,nn1", "mm,GATO,nn2", "mm,PERRO,nn1", "mm,PERRO,nn2", "mm,LOBO,nn1", "mm,LOBO,nn2"]
```

If for some reason you really want to use `each_index` and you're sure you always have double words:

```
array.each_index do |i|
  array[i] << (i % 2 + 1).to_s
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
num = "1"
array.each_with_index do |string, index|
    array[index] = string + num
    num = num == "1" ? "2" : "1"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Since all of the even indexed elements need a "1" and all odd elements need a "2", I would make a hash that maps evenness to "1" and oddness to "2", then map the array `#with_index`, appending each element with its correct value.

```
index_is_even = { true => "1", false => "2" }

array.map.with_index  {  |el, i| el + index_is_even[i % 2 == 0] }
```

Comment: You can check eveness with `even?` and oddness with `odd?`.

Comment: Totally! Something like

`array.map.with_index { |el, i| el + (i.even? ? "1" : "2") }` ?

Comment: Almost, you need to call `even?` on `i` not `el`. So the block would be something like `{ |el, i| el + (i.even? ? "1" : "2") }`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have groups of the same words of unknown length and order, you can do:

```
> array.group_by {|e| e}.values.map{|a| a.map.with_index(1) {|w, i| w << i.to_s}}.flatten
["mm,GATO,nn1", "mm,GATO,nn2", "mm,PERRO,nn1", "mm,PERRO,nn2", "mm,LOBO,nn1", "mm,LOBO,nn2"]
```

That will modify `array` in place. If you want a new array, you can do:

```
> array.group_by {|e| e}.values.map{|ar| ar.map.with_index(1) {|w, i| "%s%i" % [w, i] }}.flatten
```

If you know that your target words are only in ordered pairs, you can also do:

```
> array.each_slice(2).map{|l| l.zip(['1','2']).map(&:join)}.flatten
["mm,GATO,nn1", "mm,GATO,nn2", "mm,PERRO,nn1", "mm,PERRO,nn2", "mm,LOBO,nn1", "mm,LOBO,nn2"]
```